# Python using Tkinter moving Labels and Entry boxes

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a code which uses Tkinter I just cant arrange the places of the Labels and Entry boxes can someone help me with it. My code is down below and it's print out is Figure1. I want it to seem like Figure2.

```
import Tkinter

main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
main_window.geometry("320x400")
main_window.title("Address")

label = Tkinter.Label(main_window,text ="Name:")
label.pack()


nameentry = Tkinter.Entry(main_window) 
nameentry.pack()


label2 = Tkinter.Label(main_window, text= "Address:")
label2.pack()

addressentry = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
addressentry.pack()

label3 = Tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Phone Number:")
label3.pack()

numberentry = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
numberentry.pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

[Figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn4i3.png)

[Figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHgY9.png)

Comment: Have you read any documentation on `pack` or `grid`? They both have many options for controlling size, alignment, etc.

Comment: I tried both of them but grid doesn't work for me or I can't make it work. Pack only makes it left or right couldn't figure out well.

Comment: Something like this `grid(row=0, column=0)` should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly want things laid out in a grid, so `grid` is a better choice than `pack`.

Your layout has three rows and two columns. Labels go in column 0 (zero), and you want them anchored to the top-right (north-east, represented as "ne"). The input fields go in the second column column 1 (one).

It looks something like this (extra space added for clarity, it's not required):

```
label.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky="ne")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ne")
label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ne")

nameentry.grid(   row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
addressentry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
numberentry.grid( row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

One final step is to tell tkinter what to do with any extra space it has. In your case you probably want the label column to be as small as possible, and the input fields to be as big as possible. Also, the address appears to be multiline (though you're using an Entry widget which only accepts a single line).

To accomplish that we want to give the middle row and the right column a positive weight, which tkinter uses to know how to allocate extra space:

```
main_window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it worked. But I got one more question. Is there a way of getting the Entry box for address bigger like in the picture ?

Comment: @AliBeyit: if you want it to be multiline, use a `Text` widget.